# Why I've got gnome snap insalled when using kubuntu?

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, snap

I got a fresh Kubuntu 20.04 installation. I've got some snaps out of the box, and one of those confuses me:

```
Name               Version                     Rev   Tracking       Publisher   Notes
bitwarden          1.18.0                      25    latest/stable  bitwarden✓  -
core18             20200427                    1754  latest/stable  canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804    3.28.0-17-gde3d74c.de3d74c  128   latest/stable  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-36-gc75f853             1506  latest/stable  canonical✓  -
snapd              2.45.1                      8140  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd
```

Why do I have `gnome-3-28-1804` snap installed out of the box when I run Kubuntu with KDE Plasma? I'd expect it when running Ubuntu, but seeing it on Kubuntu is weird.

Comment: It provides the Desktop Environment (including Gnome and KDE and others) connection for other snaps (like bitwarden). The snap environment is deliberately constrained - snaps cannot talk to most of your desktop environment directly.

Comment: @user535733, but why is it named gnome, not some kind of "connnector"? Also, it's description says that `his snap includes a GNOME 3.28 stack (the base libraries and desktop
  integration components) and shares it through the content interface.`, and I probably don't need gnome stack on my KDE-based machine, do I?

Comment: Lots of things in life have funny or misleading names.